# Unit tests not running (loading) in Odoo 12

Tags: python, unit-testing, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to write unit tests for my custom module codes in Odoo 12 and I followed the official Odoo 12 documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/testing.html for writing unit tests and running my tests. but, when I run the tests according to the documentation I can't see the result of tests. It seems that the tests are not running or even loading upon server update.

I ran and updated the server following Odoo 12 documentation instructions and also applied this solution: [Why are my tests not running on Odoo 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860080/why-are-my-tests-not-running-on-odoo-10). but I still couldn't get see the test results.

The tests directory in my module is as follow:

```
├── tests
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_loan_request.py
```

I have the following code in my **init**.py file:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from . import  test_loan_request
```

and in test_loan_request.py I used these codes to for a simple test:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo.tests.common import TransactionCase, tagged


@tagged('loan')
class TestLoanRequest(TransactionCase):

    def test_loan_request_selection(self):
        print(':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: In test method')
        loan_request = self.env['loan.request'].create({'selection': 'employee', 'amount': 5000 })
        self.assertEqual(loan_request.selection, 'employee')
        print('::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: After assertEqual')
```

I used the following commands to update and run unit tests in my modules:

```
./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons,../12.e,../netlinks-erp/addons -d netlinks_erp --xmlrpc-port=9000 --test-enable --test-tags hr_payroll_advance_request,loan
```

And the this is the result which I get by running above command:

```
2019-06-23 10:12:22,739 14712 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0 
2019-06-23 10:12:22,740 14712 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/ibrahim/.local/share/Odoo/addons/12.0', '/home/ibrahim/workspace/odoo/12.0/addons', '/home/ibrahim/workspace/odoo/12.e', '/home/ibrahim/workspace/odoo/netlinks-erp/addons', '/home/ibrahim/workspace/odoo/12.0/odoo/addons'] 
2019-06-23 10:12:22,740 14712 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default 
2019-06-23 10:12:22,979 14712 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 
2019-06-23 10:12:23,259 14712 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on ubuntu:9000 
2019-06-23 10:12:23,284 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2019-06-23 10:12:23,322 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.04s, 0 queries 
2019-06-23 10:12:23,494 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.modules.loading: loading 135 modules... 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,186 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.addons.sms.wizard.send_sms: The `phonenumbers` Python module is not available. Phone number validation will be skipped. Try `pip3 install phonenumbers` to install it. 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,501 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model generate.session.wizard has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,502 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model event.session has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,502 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model event.attendance has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,799 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.overtime has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,799 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.late has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,800 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.late.line has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,801 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.absence has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,801 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.absence.line has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,802 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.diff has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,803 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.diff.line has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,803 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.policies has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,804 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.attendance.policies.line has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,807 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.public.holidays has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,888 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.academic has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,888 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model hr.experience has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,891 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model skill.skill has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:24,892 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model job.type has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:25,123 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model wiz.reject.ts has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:25,222 14712 WARNING netlinks_erp odoo.models: The model wiz.hr.emp.attendance has no _description 
2019-06-23 10:12:25,244 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.modules.loading: 135 modules loaded in 1.75s, 0 queries 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,736 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,736 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,736 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,737 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,737 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,737 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,737 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,737 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,738 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,738 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,738 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,738 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field account.analytic.line.sheet_id depends on non-stored field account.analytic.line.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,773 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,773 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,775 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,775 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,776 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,776 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,776 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,776 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,777 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,777 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,777 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,777 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.fields: Field hr.attendance.sheet_id depends on non-stored field hr.attendance.sheet_id_computed 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,896 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded. 
2019-06-23 10:12:27,915 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.service.server: Starting post tests 
2019-06-23 10:12:28,366 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.service.server: All post-tested in 0.45s, 0 queries 
2019-06-23 10:12:28,397 14712 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files 
2019-06-23 10:12:28,404 14712 WARNING ? odoo.http: Logged into database 'test_db', but dbfilter rejects it; logging session out. 
2019-06-23 10:12:28,406 14712 INFO netlinks_erp odoo.addons.base.models.ir_http: Generating routing map 
2019-06-23 10:12:28,647 14712 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
```

How can I run the unit tests which I have them in tests directory in my module and see the results of the tests?

Comment: check the db_filter param in your odoo conf. I think that is restricting to load your db.

Comment: @Burmesepythis-HilarAK, I got a clone from Odoo 12 repository in GitHub and I didn't configure or change anything in Odoo conf file. Also, I ran the server with `--db_filter=netlinks_erp` but still nothing loaded or ran. If I should change anything in the odoo conf file, what should I change there?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are missing the -u your_module_to_test in the command line

Comment: I have used the above command when updating the server several times, but it still doesn't get any effect.

Comment: did you manage to fix it? my comment was based on the part that you didn't specify in the command line the -u to your module, without it, it will run only the server with the database.

Comment: Actually, I still couldn't run my own tests and I tried many solutions, but my tests didn't run.

Comment: join the developers in telegram we can help in person in there, if you find help there came later to post the solution, just find in telegram odoo devs